# How to handle left joins on large tables? Having unexpected behaviors

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony

I’m having an issue with my SQL query:

Table price counts millions of lines and must be queried properly. Everything was running fine and the page took ~400ms to load until I made an update on the DB (updated it with a new DB from our Prod DB) and it broke everything. It now takes 120s to load the page.

It’s running just fine on our prod and pre prod environments but is super slow on my dev env. I’m running with the same mysql version and php version. Using Symfony 4 with doctrine 2 ORM.

The query i’m working on is the following:

```
SELECT 
c0_.id AS id_0, 
c0_.ticker AS ticker_1, 
c0_.name AS name_2, 
p1_.id AS id_3, 
p1_.rank AS rank_4, 
p1_.price_usd AS price_usd_5, 
p1_.1d_volume_usd AS 1d_volume_usd_6, 
p1_.change_1h AS change_1h_7, 
p1_.change_1d AS change_1d_8, 
p1_.change_7d AS change_7d_9, 
c2_.id AS id_10, 
c2_.market_cap AS market_cap_11, 
s3_.id AS id_12, 
s3_.score_buzz AS score_buzz_13, 
s3_.score_average AS score_average_14 
FROM coins c0_ 
LEFT JOIN prices p1_ ON c0_.id = p1_.ticker_id 
AND (p1_.last_updated >= ?) LEFT JOIN cmc c2_ ON c0_.id = c2_.ticker_id 
AND (c2_.last_updated >= ?) LEFT JOIN scores s3_ ON c0_.id = s3_.ticker_id 
AND (s3_.to_datetime >= ?) 
WHERE c0_.is_active = 1 ORDER BY c0_.rank_cmc ASC, p1_.last_updated DESC, c2_.last_updated DESC, s3_.to_datetime DESC
```

the problem comes from that part:

```
LEFT JOIN prices p1_ ON c0_.id = p1_.ticker_id AND (p1_.last_updated >= ?)
```

If I remove this part it works just fine.
Where could the pb come from? why am i having 2 different behaviors (prod and dev) for the same query ? 
How do you usually handle left join on big tables?

Thank you

EDIT:
Here is the explain of the query in DEV:
[image]

Here is the explain of the query in PROD:
[image]

EDIT2:
Dev indexes on price:
[image]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I’m using mysql

Comment: Did you try EXPLAIN keyword to see which indexing are used? and will show how you can optimize it

Comment: Can you view the query plan on the production server, then compare it to the query plan on the development server?  That might help find the root cause.  It could be an index problem, as your non-equi join is going to always be troublesome.  It could be that the statistics in production are different to your development database, or that the actual data itself is different?

Comment: Check if you have index defined on ticker_id column of prices table. Also define a partition on last_updated column.

Comment: @mukund: Thank you, I added the result of EXPLAIN

Comment: @Richard: Thanks, How can I view the query plan on the server? They are supposed to be identical (same version, same structure).

Comment: Query Plan = EXPLAIN, it's just terminology.  My point is that if the production/ development servers are indeed identical, that this is probably a problem due to statistics, etc. being different between environments, which would result in two different EXPLAINs.

Comment: @GauravS: I’ve created an index on ticker_id but it didn’t help much (+25% faster but still way too slow). Should I be looking at mysql parameters maybe? how much memory should I allocate considering the 10Go DB ?

Comment: @Richard: Thanks, I provided both screenshots and updated my question. There is indeed a different on the price line, one say Using Join Buffer (in prod) but the one in dev says Range checked for each record. Is this where this comes from ? How could I change that? thanks

Comment: @MilesM. Please provide the list of keys, I cannot see most of the fields are index which are used in join and where clause. Try to add index to field which are used for "on" and "where" clause

Comment: Sure, for the price table, last_updated and ticker id are indexed in a search_idx index as shown on the screenshot (see edit2) . Thx

Answer (score 1):

Look at the prod and dev explain Query, on p1_ line for 'key' column:
In dev it's NULL
In prod it's search_idx.

Conclusion : if you run "bin/console d:s:u --dump-sql " in prod and dev environement, you need to find some diffence in dB schema.

Comment: Thanks Lasouze, but unfortunately the structure of the DB is exactly the same, from Dev to Prod, therefore why I’m struggling with this, feels like it something is different from the explain select but i can’t figure out how to fix it and change my DB settings to behave like on prod. Thx

Comment: Can we force sql to use an index? Cause I think you’re right, this is where the issue is coming from but for some reason it’s not using the index in the select query where it should be using it.

Answer (score 1):

There could be numerous reason. You are seeing fast result on your dev server as there are less records while your live server consist of lots of records(refer `rows` column in explain statement).

I recommend to check all the keys and your `join` column type. Each column used in join with "`on`" clause should have similar type else it will be slowed down. So make sure columns are `int+unsigned` or `varchar` etc.

Look for the `possible_key, key and extra` column in your output and try to understand from the following link which will help you find the proper solution

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html

Also refer section "EXPLAIN Output Interpretation" from the above link.

Comment: Thanks mukund for this answer, there are the same amount of results between dev and prod, the dev DB is an export/import of prod with the exact same structure and data.  I have checked all the keys & indexes of of my joined columns (price table) and they are the same. 

From what I understand, looking at the explain, it seems SQL is not using the index in the select query in dev when it’s using it in prod. Why so?

Comment: I see, indexes are added for: `rank, ticker_id and last_updated` what is the use of rank here?
`LEFT JOIN prices p1_ ON c0_.id = p1_.ticker_id 
AND (p1_.last_updated >= ?)` 
Try to add index to above columns `id, ticker_id, last_updated`

Comment: You can also force it by ` FROM X  WITH (INDEX(search_idx))`

Comment: id is the primary key, do I need to index it as well?

Comment: Then remove the rank atleast as its not used anywhere

Comment: Thanks for helping, unfortunately, it isn’t doing much. I’m a bit clueless :/ Where do you think I should look to?